# Remove Null values in JSON and Update JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON Array as a string by serializing a list using Newtonsoft as below

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"somename","Class":"12","Section":null},{"ID":null,"Name":"somename","Class":"13","Section":null},{"ID":2,"Name":"somename","Class":null,"Section":"A"}]
```

I need to convert this JSON by removing the `NULL` values to another JSONString like below

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"somename","Class":"12",},{"Name":"somename","Class":"13",},{"ID":2,"Name":"somename","Section":"A"}]
```

Is there a way I can use Newtonsoft for this or how do i do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `JsonSerializerSettings` with `NullValueHandling`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings() 
            { 
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
            });
```