# How to remove null values from IEnumerables when parsing JSON with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.Net to parse JSON into my app logic.
The problem is that the external API that I get the JSON from sometimes has "null" items inside their lists.
I would like to remove those "null" items from the list (or any other IEnumerable that might have that) at parse time. 
I believe the solution has to be using a JsonConverter but I was unable to get it working so far.

```
MyData data = new MyData();
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
  Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new TrimNullListValues() }
};
string jsonString = @"{""ListData"": [{""source"" : 10 , ""target"" : 20, ""Data"" : [{""source"" : 100 , ""target"" : 200}, null]}, null]}";
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, data, settings);
```

MyData class is like this:

```
public class MyData {
  public class MyNestedData
  {
    public int Source;
    public int Target;
    public List<MyNestedData> Data;
  }

  public List<MyNestedData> ListData;
}
```

My JsonConverter (TrimNullListValues) is like this:

```
public class TrimNullListValues : JsonConverter {
  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    // Don't really know what to do in here to remove unwanted values
    // From the IEnumerabes
  }

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
  }
}
```

Comment: See if it helps to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455837/remove-null-values-in-json-and-update-json

Comment: No that doesn't work for me :( It would work if the whole list was null but not for values inside the list. Thx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
    foreach (JToken item in array.ToList())
    {
        if (item.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            item.Remove();
    }
    object list = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    serializer.Populate(array.CreateReader(), list);
    return list;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SESCfZ

Comment: Thanks it works fine for that example. But if i have a list inside "MyNestedData" with some null values those are not removed. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ojnMWd

Comment: Oh, your structure is recursive?  You probably should have mentioned that in the question.  I've updated my answer.